# What is the correct way to fix an assertion in loadlocale.c?

Tags: 18.04, locale, language-support

I have recently updated Ubuntu to 18.04. After this, issuing the command `ld` constantly failed with the following assertion:

```
loadlocale.c:129: _nl_intern_locale_data: Assertion `cnt < (sizeof (_nl_value_type_LC_TIME) / sizeof (_nl_value_type_LC_TIME[0]))' failed.
```

I have googled this problem and it looks like this is a well known issue. All of the solutions that I have read suggested fixing this using the following command:

```
export LC_ALL=C
```

See, for example, [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49301627/android-7-1-2-armv7). However, doing so breaks fonts of the commentaries on my native language in VIM for example.

So, this solution is not suitable for me-. Are there any other ways to fix this issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had this problem on Ubuntu 14 trusty, I solved it as follows.

First, edit `/etc/locale.gen` and add the locales you want.

Make sure the `utf8` in the locale name is lowercase, not e.g. `UTF-8`.

So mine are:

```
en_US.utf8
ru_RU.utf8
```

Now run, as root:

```
rm -f /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive
locale-gen --no-archive
locale-gen --no-archive en_US.utf8
locale-gen --no-archive ru_RU.utf8
```

the `--no-archive` flag is important.

Now make sure in your startup files like `~/.bash_profile` and `~/.bashrc` etc. you set `LANG` and related variables to the lowercase `utf8` form, see the directories in `/usr/lib/locale` for the correct form.

Comment: This worked for me on Ubuntu 18.04 but with the following modifications: 1. use en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8 in locale.gen
2. then locale-gen --no-archive en_US.UTF-8

Answer (score 12):

As easy as:

```
export LC_ALL=C
```

and then run your command. LC_ALL works as a fallback if something is not set (like LC_TIME in your case)

Comment: Why has this received any upvotes whatsoever? This is the "solution" (or shall we say workaround) mentioned by the person asking. And there is a rationale as to why this workaround doesn't work.

Answer (score -1):

I added this to my .bashrc and it fixed the issue for both Ubuntu 18 and 20 when I was having that same message with an old 32 bit gdb for an Arm cross compiler

export LANG=C

Comment: be warned, a side effect is this changes the order of `sort`